# Oracle rename function syntax

Tags: oracle, function, rename

How to change **function** name in **oracle**? Is that possible to change function name in oracle ? If yes I used that **function** a lot of in **queries**, will it change automatically or i have to change all of it ?

Comment: You need to recreate the function with a new name and drop the old one. No, old names of the function will not automatically be replaced by new one in your queries or anywhere else.

Comment: Please try to clarify what you re asking, its kinda vague how this is worded.
About the second part of your question, all moden IDEs have a function to refactor changes including renames so the system can check all usage of the function within scope and rename it for you.

Comment: @Leon sorry about that. I created function in oracle and i used it a lot of queries. I want to change this function name that's what i would like to ask

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Krasnov. Do you have any suggestions to fix it easily?

Comment: @Jenny if I understand correctly, using the refactor feature is your best choice. Feel free to read more on SO for this, there is an ample amount of material available on this.

Comment: If you change the name of a function, you will have to change it everywhere that name is used. Depending on why you want to change the name, it may not be worth the time.

Comment: You can change the name of a function rather easily (recreate it or put it inside a function with a new name), but if the function is referenced in many places you need to decide (as @Rene noted) whether it's worth the time? if it is, then you need to replace the old name of the function by the new one, manually,  everywhere old name of the function is being referenced.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov thank you i searched it little bit i think i can use **LIKE** for change function name from where i used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that possible to change function name in oracle?

You cannot, you will need to create a new function with a different name and then drop the old function if you want the function to be renamed.

> If yes I used that function a lot of in queries, will it change automatically or i have to change all of it?

You will have to go through everywhere it has been used and change it manually.

**Alternative**:

You could create a synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM your_new_function_name FOR your_old_function_name;
```

Then you could use both the new and the old name. However, this would not actually rename the function; just give it an additional synonym.

```
DROP FUNCTION your_old_function_name;
CREATE FUNCTION your_new_function_name -- ...
CREATE SYNONYM your_old_function_name FOR your_new_function_name;
```

You could also drop the function and recreate it with a new name and then put a synonym in for the old name (so you do not have to change any of the existing queries).